# macOS Sierra Sites folder on iCloud Drive how to localhost?

Tags: apache, localhost, macos-sierra, icloud-drive

I have moved my Sites folder to iCloud Drive and symlinked a Sites alias from the home folder, for ease of use, in Terminal etc. This works neatly for my rails apps with Webrick server.

Now I would like to use it with Apache, for non rails Sites.

How can I set localhost/~username to use Sites in iCloud Drive?
I get "You don't have permission to access /~username/ on this server."

(I know how to and succeed if the Sites folder - not an alias - is in the home folder. I checked the setup. It works.)

Answer (score 3):

I put my sites folder for my website development in my iCloud Drive.  Both my desktop computer and my laptop are always in sync with the latest development folder automatically.    To do this, you have to edit your httpd.conf file and your private host files.   In the httpd.conf file, you must change the user that is running Apache so that it can access the iCloud drive.

In httpd.conf find the lines for the User and Group and edit them:

```html
<IfModule unixd_module>
#
# If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run
# httpd as root initially and it will switch.  
#
# User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
# It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
# running httpd, as with most system services.
#
User <Edit in your username without the brackets>
Group admin

</IfModule>
```

Now in the Virtual Hosts File: httpd-vhosts.conf - edit your director location for your website.   The location of the iCloud directory begins with:  /Users/yourusername/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs and must be quoted because of the blank in directory name.

```html
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domainname.com
 DocumentRoot "/Users/yourusername/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Sites/YourDomainsRootDirectory"
 <Directory "/Users/yourusername/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Sites/YourDomainsRootDirectory">
    AllowOverride All
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    Require all granted
 </Directory>
    ServerName yourdomainname.com
    ServerAlias dev.yourdomainname.com
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/yourdomainname.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/yourdomainname.com-access_log" common 
</VirtualHost>
```

Then restart Apache